# Random rectangles as array

Tags: javascript

When I run this code as  html,  the rectangles won't come up properly

Any idea to get a proper outcome?

Thank you for your help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>My Website</h1>

    <p>This is my first website</p>
<script>
var w=(Math.floor(Math.random()*10))+2;
document.write("width:"+(w+1));
var h=(Math.floor(Math.random()*10))+3;
document.write("height:"+h);
var cua = new Array;
cua[0]="|";
cua[w]="|";

for (i=1;i<w;i++){
    cua[i]=" ";
}
//base y techo
var bas = new Array;

for (k=0;k<(w+1);k++){
    bas[k]="-";
}

document.write(bas.join(""));//techo

for (j=1;j<(h+1);j++){
    document.write(cua.join(""));
}
//join quita las comas
document.write(bas.join(""));//base

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're `document.write`ing HTML, so runs of spaces are going to be collapsed and (if you were writing any) newlines would be converted to whitespace.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like it works different as when I just display it on the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert `<br>` to make a new line, and `&nbsp;` to insert a space.
This is kind of what you need:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>My Website</h1>

    <p>This is my first website</p>
<script>
var w=(Math.floor(Math.random()*10))+2;
document.write("width:"+(w+1));
var h=(Math.floor(Math.random()*10))+3;
document.write("height:"+h);
var cua = new Array;
cua[0]="|";
cua[w]="|";

for (i=1;i<w;i++){
    cua[i]="&nbsp;";
}
//base y techo
var bas = new Array;

for (k=0;k<(w+1);k++){
    bas[k]="-";
}
document.write("<br>");
document.write(bas.join(""));//techo
document.write("<br>");
for (j=1;j<(h+1);j++){
    document.write(cua.join(""));
     document.write("<br>");
}
//join quita las comas
document.write(bas.join(""));//base

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```